# Entity Framwork Core + Linq: How do I get the entire entity that has the max value? Looking for a more elegant solution

Tags: c#, linq, .net-core, entity-framework-core

This is what I have so far:

```
var TEST = await context.ProcessRevision.FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.ProcessRevId == (context.ProcessRevision.Max(i => i.ProcessRevId)));
```

I am unsure whether this is a good solution or if I could do something a little more elegant with less processing.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just sort it in descending order and get the first entity. Most likely this is EF context? So it should be translated into a `select top (1)` with `order by ... desc`.

```cs
var test = await context.ProcessRevision.OrderByDescending(r => r.ProcessRevId).FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```